# Overload method return type based on class type argument

Tags: typescript

Say I have this class:

```
class Test<T> {
    stuff: T;

    // these lines don't compile :(
    // whatIsStuff(this: Test<any[]>): string
    // whatIsStuff(this: Test<any>): number

    whatIsStuff() {
        if(this.stuff instanceof Array)
            return "an array"
        else
            return 1
    }
}
```

How can I describe the return value of `whatIsStuff()`? I was hoping the commented out lines would be valid, but it complains about the presence of `this`.

This works just fine if I have a free function:

```
function whatIsStuffFor(a: Test<any[]>): string
function whatIsStuffFor(a: Test<any>): number
function whatIsStuffFor(a: Test<any>): any {
    if(this.stuff instanceof Array)
        return "an array"
    else
        return 1
}
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20class%20Test%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stuff%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20these%20lines%20don't%20compile%20%3A(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20whatIsStuff(this%3A%20Test%3Cany%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20whatIsStuff(this%3A%20Test%3Cany%3E)%3A%20number%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20whatIsStuff()%3A%20number%20%7C%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(this.stuff%20instanceof%20Array)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22an%20array%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Afunction%20whatIsStuffFor(a%3A%20Test%3Cany%5B%5D%3E)%3A%20string%0D%0Afunction%20whatIsStuffFor(a%3A%20Test%3Cany%3E)%3A%20number%0D%0Afunction%20whatIsStuffFor(a%3A%20Test%3Cany%3E)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(this.stuff%20instanceof%20Array)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22an%20array%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x1%20%3D%20whatIsStuffFor(new%20Test%3Cnumber%5B%5D%3E())%3B%0D%0Avar%20y1%20%3D%20whatIsStuffFor(new%20Test%3Cstring%5B%5D%3E())%3B%0D%0Avar%20x2%20%3D%20(new%20Test%3Cnumber%5B%5D%3E()).whatIsStuff()%3B%0D%0Avar%20y2%20%3D%20(new%20Test%3Cstring%5B%5D%3E()).whatIsStuff()%3B)

Comment: Appreciate you boiling it down like this, but what is the use case?

Comment: Adding a type definition for [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)'s `promise<T>.all()`, which has different behavior for different types of T.

Comment: `Promise<[Promise<A>, Promise<B>]>.all() => Promise<[A, B]>`, but `Promise<A>` is unchanged (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you can use a union type to describe the `string or number` return type:

```
class Test<T> {
    stuff: T;

    constructor(value : T) {
        this.stuff = value;
    }

    whatIsStuff() : string | number {
        if (this.stuff instanceof Array)
            return "an array";
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

var x = new Test("foobar")
var y = new Test([1, 2])

console.log(x.whatIsStuff()) // 1
console.log(y.whatIsStuff()) // an array
```

Comment: Right, but does typescript allow me to do `x.whatIsStuff() * 2`? Or does it think it's still an union that needs resolving?

Comment: It does think of it as a union. Does the input type `T` has any relationship with the return type of `whatIsStuff`? If not then I'm afraid that using `any` as your return type is the solution.

Comment: Other than a mapping between the type of T and the return type, no. What annoys me is that this works just fine as a free function

Comment: That's because it can resolve the appropriate overload at the call site when using a free function. That's not possible with an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, and my proposed syntax works just fine as of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739